# Convert Object to JSON Object

Tags: javascript

I am using DataTables library and I have hard times in receiving data in a proper format so I am trying to adjust it before DataTable library tries to fetch data into table. I have an ajax call which returns an object of the following format:

```
data:[ [{ Key: "SomeKey" , Value: "SomeValue" } , { ...} ],[...] ]
```

And my desired output is: `data:[ [{ "SomeKey":"SomeValue" } , { ...} ],[...] ]`

I have tried JSON.stringify or eval method , but did not worked , also tried those 2 methods when return type was some sort of string but then it inserts `\` before `"` so It does not convert to json. Any help or good tracks would be appreciated.

Comment: if your ajax call returns the STRING you show, then it can not be easily converted to a javascript object and then to JSON - fix the server that responds with such useless format :p If, however, when you say `object` it is an object, then JSON.stringify will make it into JSON

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. What you want to do here is purely to convert an array of objects with the keys (property names) `Key` and `Value` into an array of objects with a property from the `Key` value and the value from `Value`.

Comment: `then it inserts \ before "` - no, that's just how the console shows it, don't get hung up in console output - if you're seeing `\"` then it probably is already JSON, and you need to JSON.parse it to start "using" it in javascript (as an object)

Comment: Btw the \ before " just lets the interpreter know not to interpret. ;-)

Comment: @JaromandaX in my server I have tried using JObject  which is a class of Newtonsoft JSON library ( c# ) , but if I use that I get the data in a very strange format : Array of Array of Array of empty Array , so I get nothing beside  the same number of items in Array as I see in server method , and to mention as I used breakpoint when server returns data and at server they are in a good format

Comment: @Nikolaus I know what does that char but if you print a JSON object in console  I am pretty sure you won't see any     `\`

Comment: Could you please add the Server-Method-Code? As I watch at you second question i expect it to be c#!? Maybe it has something to do with the Response-format.

Comment: @Nikolaus Action type was ActionResult and return type was Json but I don't think it has anything to do with it as I had switched to JsonResult and it is the same output. I have ExpandoObjects which I am adding into a list of object then I am returning Json( new { data = myListOfObjects } )

Comment: This means you’ve found your solution.

Comment: Well yea pretty much yes , it is the solution to what I asked but my job is not done yet , but hopefully now I can do on my own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with JSON. :-)

`data` is apparently an array of arrays of objects, where each object has properties valled `Key` and `Value`.

If you want to create a new array of arrays of objects, where the objects have a property named by the `Key` value whose value is the `Value` value, you can do that like this:

```
data = data.map(a => a.map(({Key,Value}) => ({[Key]: Value})));
```

That uses [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the arrays (both the outer and inner ones) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pick out the `Key` and `Value` properties from each object in the subarrays, and uses [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) to set the property name on the new object.

In ES5 and earlier, that would look like this:

```
data = data.map(function(a) {
    return a.map(function(obj) {
        var newObj = {};
        newObj[obj.Key] = obj.Value;
        return newObj;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should look into `Array.prototype.map` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

```js
let data = [[{Key: "SomeKey", Value: "SomeValue"}]];
let output = data.map(a => a.map(({Key, Value}) => ({[Key]: Value})));
console.log(output);
```

Note the `[Key]` syntax. To put it simply, whereas `var x = 'key'; y = {x: 3}` will assign the object `{x: 3}`, `x = 'key'; y = {[x]: 3}` will assign the object `{key: 3}`.

If you're receiving literally the string `"data:[ [{ Key: "SomeKey" , Value: "SomeValue" } , { ...} ],[...] ]"`, then you may trim the first 5 characters ('data:') and then use `JSON.parse`.